# how to convert date format from yyyy-m-dd (1990-1-01) to yyyy-mm-dd (1990-01-01) in R?

Tags: r

I just want to get the date in `YYYY-MM-DD`. I have the date in `YYYY-M-DD` format. In the source file, date is in YYYY-M FORMAT.
Here is my code:

```
DATA2<-transform(Data, Date = paste(Date, "01", sep = "-"))
DATA2$Date<-as.Date(DATA2$Date)
```

Comment: `lubridate::ymd('1990-1-01')`

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `Date` class and then format it.  No packages are needed.

```
format(as.Date("1990-1-01"))
## [1] "1990-01-01"
```

Comment: Why not just `as.Date("1990-1-01")`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as.character`

```
as.character(as.Date("1990-1-01"))
```